# SSRS 2011 SQL where with case when

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a boolean parameter in ssrs.

How do I write the query to achive the folowing:

boolean parameter @isMultiple (value is true or false)

the SQL Query is:

```
Select employee from employeeTable
WHERE 
CASE @isMultiple 
WHEN 'True' then employeeID in(@EmployeeIDSelected)
WHEN 'False' then EmployeeID=@EmployeeID
END
```

Thank you

Comment: Case is an expression that returns *a single value*, not a statement that can be used for control-of-flow. Read [Dirty Secrets of the CASE Expression](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `CASE` in `WHERE` but you can use `OR`. Try something like

```
SELECT employee
FROM employeeTable
WHERE (@isMultiple = 'True' AND employeeID IN (@EmployeeIDSelected))
   OR (@isMultiple = 'False' AND EmployeeID = @EmployeeID)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use CASE, you could do something like this:

```
Select employee from employeeTable
WHERE 1 = 
(CASE @isMultiple 
WHEN 'True' then (CASE WHEN employeeID in(@EmployeeIDSelected) THEN 1 END)
WHEN 'False' then (CASE WHEN EmployeeID=@EmployeeID THEN 1 END)
END)
```

You might want to check query plans before deciding if it was worthwhile, though.